# Is this an identity?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

$$\ln|\sin(x/2)|-\ln|\cos(x/2)|=-\ln(|\csc(x)+\cot(x)|)$$

Microsoft mathematics says that $\int(\csc \theta$) is the former, whereas my text says it is the latter

Comment: Hint: $\ln x - \ln y = \ln x /y$ and $\ln x + \ln y = \ln x y$

Comment: Thomas Andrews gave an excellent answer. An alternative for this kind of question (with often very simple computations) is to compute the derivatives of both expressions and show that they are equal. This means that the functions differ only by a constant (on any interval). Showing they take the same value at one point means the two functions are actually equal. I don't write it as an answer, since the computation are not simpler here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using $\ln(a)-\ln(b)=\ln(a/b)$, you get the left side is $\ln|\tan(x/2)|$

Now, note that $$\csc(x)+\cot(x)=\frac{1}{\sin(x)} +\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)} = \frac{1+\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}$$

Finally, remember your tangent half-angle formula:

$$\tan(x/2)=\frac{\sin(x)}{1+\cos (x)}$$

So $$\frac{1}{\csc(x)+\cot(x)} = \tan(x/2).$$

Then take the absolute value of both sides and then the logarithm.